# SonicWALL SRA blocks load test as a DoS attack

Tags: sonicwall, load-testing, web-application-firewall

I am evaluating the Web Application Firewall (WAF) service on a SonicWALL SRA virtual appliance. When I try to load test the protected website, SonicWALL blocks my requests with this error: "Reset connection to prevent Denial of Service attack - too many connections received from the same client". These errors are appearing in the main system log, not in the WAF log.

Is there a way to make SonicWALL allow the barrage of requests from my client, passing them through to its WAF service?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by lowering the number of load test clients from 25 to 20. After doing so, the device no longer dropped my requests as a DoS attack.